# My Website displaying big IIS7 screen when access

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7

We have taken a domain for our asp.net application. That application  is deployed in our server (IIS7).. when we are trying to access that website its showing one big IIS7 screen..
can you pls let me know the issue.

Regards,
Abhi[image]

Comment: What is the name of your start page? Try default.aspx or index.aspx

Comment: error came : -- I have given like http://www.mywebsitename.co.xx/login.aspx ... 404 error came

Answer (score 0):

Is your application definitely deployed at the root of the website in IIS or is it deployed as a virtual directory?
Because this is the behaviour I would expect if it is deployed as a virtual directory.